# How to test parsed from the web data?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I have a program which captures some data from the Internet and performors some actions on it. Very basic code:

```
class ParsedData:

    data = None

    def _get(self):
        self.data = requests.get('...')

    def method1(self):
        self._get()

    def method2(self):
        self._get()
```

How do I need to test `method1` and `method2`? Do I need to provide my own web-like data in the `TestCase` and not get it from the web at all, or I can just test it with real data from the web and check weather the results of the program are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests usually use [mocks](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) for objects/methods that utilize network, databases, etc. This approach makes the tests very fast and also doesn't require any special 'environment'.

Thus you can mock the `_get()` method of the class and then insure that `method1()`, `method2()`, etc. process the data correctly.